# Difference between jconsole and jstat output

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, memory-management

I am observing different output from jstate and jconsole at the particular time.

**Jstat output :**

Monday, December 24, 2012 09:52:28 PM JST

Timestamp         S0     S1     E      **O**      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT

938.9  91.19  69.22 **100.00**  99.98  66.60    153   20.799     6    2.271   23.070

**jConsole Output :**

[image]

At particular time jstat showing **O** is 100 % but jconsole not.I don't know why ?

Anyone have any idea ??

Answer (score 0):

jstat‘s output is GC in Old Par.When Old Par'gc can't work well, All Heap GC(Full gc) work.Jconsole's output is the latter.
this url maybe explain 
http://javabook.compuware.com/content/memory/analyzing-java-memory.aspx